# Do Invocations duplicating spells count as Spell-like abilities of those spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

[Title](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48434/can-at-wills-be-spent-on-other-abilities#comment96945_48434) straight from [MrLemon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/10979/mrlemon).

For example, "A 1st-level dragonfire adept begins with knowledge of one least invocation[...]. [...] See Draconic Invocations, below, for a list of available invocations." (Dragon Magic, p.25).

> DARKNESS
>   **Least; 2nd**
>       You can create magical darkness, as the *darkness* spell (*PH* 216).

(p.79)

Then there is the BiS feat:

> BLEND INTO SHADOWS
>       You can draw from nearby magical 
>   shadow to cloak yourself in darkness.
>           **Prerequisite:** *Darkness* as a spell-like 
>   ability.
>           **Benefit:** As a swift action, you can spend a use of your *darkness* spell-like ability to make a Hide check, even while being observed and without cover or concealment. You must be within 10 feet of an area of magical *darkness*.
>       You also gain one additional daily use of your *darkness* spell-like ability.

(Drow of the Underdark, p.47)

Can the Darkness invocation fulfill the prerequisite for the Blend into Shadows feat?
I guess an argument would be that the feat requires a spell-like ability specifically called "Darkness".

Answer (score 5):

Invocations are explicitly spell-like abilities, complete with Sp tag. You have a spell-like ability named *darkness*. That’s all you need to qualify.

Moreover, according to *Complete Arcane* pg. 72, invocations count as the spell they mimic for the purpose of prerequisites. This is a special rule for warlocks to qualify for feats and prestige classes, and would not otherwise be true. If they went out of their way to make a spell-like ability count as a spell for requirements, I think it’s pretty certain that they certainly didn’t have a problem with it counting *as what it actually is* for requirements.

Comment: Page 72, "SPECIFIC SPELL REQUIREMENTS"? Hm, I'd agree, even though there is a missing link. I guess I'll leave this for a day and accept it then.